# DIV overlapping sticky footer

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing three other divs: header, content, footer

```
  <div class="note">
    <div class="header">Title</div>
    <div class="content" contenteditable="true">Some content</div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
```

Footer is always at the bottom of the parent div. Here is some CSS:

```
.note {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.note .footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.note .content {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Middle div is for text input. The problem is that it overlaps the footer when there is too much text. I want the middle div to be a scrollable area, that does not overlap footer. It can be done with setting height of that div, but this is not good for me - the div with class 'note' will be resizable. How can I do it?

Here is working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jhsn9EziMLs6IUCUg2ah?p=preview

Comment: Add `overflow:scroll` to your .note .content

Comment: But it still overlaps footer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First things first:

Remove the absolute positioning on the footer.

```
position: absolute;
```

This takes the footer 'outside' of the normal flow of the document. So, if your content increases, the footer will always appear to 'overlap' withe the content.

Instead, use relative positioning for the footer:

```
.content {
    background-color:Orange;
    height:400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color:Black;
    color:White;

}
```

In the above code, you can change the height of the content and you will observe that the footer always stays at the bottom of the page irrespective of the 'size' of the content.

You'll also need to add a min-height to the content div so that gives the appearance taht the footer is always at the bottom of the screen. Just thought I'll let you know that!!

See this here-> http://jsfiddle.net/9dUJY/

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I can't have absolute height on `.content`. is that the only way to do it?

Comment: You can have any height on content. The footer div always stays at the bottom of the content irrespective of the hieght of content. Whether content is 2px or 100px footer will always stay below it. Thats what I wanted to point out with the fiddle :)

Comment: Try changing the value of height to 2px and 1000px in the fiddle and you'' observe that footer automatically adjusts to always stays right below the content.

Comment: The min-height is just to give the visual appearance of the page being the full size of the screen.

Comment: That is right, but when you type text in `.content` it will expand without height set. Maybe I wasn't clear in my question - I don't want it to expand, I want `.content` to scroll

Comment: See this then http://jsfiddle.net/9dUJY/2/. When you don't specify the height, the div expands to fit in its content. So the scroll doesn't really turn out to be useful. If you specify a fixed height and add scroll, the div expands only till that size after which it adds a scroll

Comment: How to have the same behavior without setting height of `.content`? I only set the height of his parent.

Comment: Check this then-> http://jsfiddle.net/9dUJY/3/ I guess this is what you're talking about. You see, here I have not set the height of content. Instead, I have set the height to its parent as you wanted. And based on the parent's size the scroll bar appears!!

Comment: `.footer` div needs to be inside `.note` :)

Comment: You will need a container div to hold the content which is why I placed the footer outside .note :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to the following:

```
.note {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.note .footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color:#fff;
  /* width:100%; */
}
.note .content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  height:60%;
}
```

Comment: Great! working like a charm. Is `width: 100%;` in .note .footer really neccessary?

Comment: no, it was just the first thing I did to make sure you can't see the content in the footer. The real issue is setting the setting the overflow-x and overflow-y then setting the height to be whatever you want to constrain it.

Comment: After some testing it turn out that this is not perfect solution. Percentage height on content div will make it have different distance from footer on different heights of note. For example on div 'note' with height 500px there will be bigger gap between 'content' and footer than on div 'note' with height 200px

Answer (score 0):

Does the height of the note need to be set at 100px? You can set a height for the footer and then put a padding-bottom in the .note equal to the footer height to keep them from overlapping. I used 30px as an example and removed the fixed height. [Try it here](http://plnkr.co/edit/03xZHErMHcWqQeK7OfIH?p=preview).

Comment: I don't want note to expand, it should always stay with the same height.

Answer (score 0):

You have no height set on your content and have not activated scroll. The fact you are adding scroll to a 100px height container makes me feel you will have a usability issue later.

[updated version](http://plnkr.co/edit/PfXJCalq0L2kDrWN33uM?p=preview)

Be aware of supported browsers, if you are working with modern instances only you will be OK. IE8 it appears is supported.

[Check the MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y#Browser_compatibility)

```
.note {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.note .footer {
  bottom: 0px;
}
.note .content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  height:70px;
}
```