# Overlapping contenteditable spans

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

Some contenteditable boxes overlap others as such not all boxes are editable. I want to preserve the text aligned to the center at the position of the spans as below. How do I achieve this?

```css
span {
  margin: auto;       
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 26.8%; left:41%">●</span>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 36.6%; left:41%">●</span>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 46.4%; left:41%">●</span>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 56.2%; left:41%">●</span>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 26.8%; left:24%">●</span>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 36.6%; left:24%">●</span>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 46.4%; left:24%">●</span>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 56.2%; left:24%">●</span>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 26.8%; left:75%">●</span>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 36.6%; left:75%">●</span>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 46.4%; left:75%">●</span>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 56.2%; left:75%">●</span>
```

Comment: Your doing everything wrong in the above code. Firstly do you want the spans one below the other or besides each other ?

Comment: I need them to be in the position they are, each

Comment: In that case all you need to do is remove everything from your style `span { }`. You have already `position`ed the spans using `top` and `left`. There is no need to use `margin: auto` to position it again(its counter-productive) and definitely not the `width: 100%`

Comment: But then the text won't be aligned to the center

Comment: center to what? In your case the `text-align: center` is also not aligning the text to the center. You have already given `top: 26.8%; left:41%` to the element so it will not be center. Put in simple terms **you cannot use `position` and `center` at the same time**. Its like first you are pushing the elements to the left and then you are telling its not center. Ofcourse it wont be since you pushed it earlier.

Comment: Is there a way of making the center of the text be in the left: 41%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution using jquery to reposition and keep it centered:

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('focus', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('before', $this.html());
    $this.data('leftbefore', $this.offset().left + ($this.width()/2));
    return $this;
}).on('blur keyup paste', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('before') !== $this.html()) {
        $this.data('before', $this.html());
        $this.trigger('change');
        $this.offset({ left:($this.data('leftbefore') - ($this.width() / 2))});
    }
    return $this;
});
```

if someone has a better solution, please do tell

Answer (score 0):

ContentEditable is the native widget for editing rich text in a web browser. Assuming you want the spans one below the other, this is how you can write your text editor.You can replace your code with this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43133418/5488850). After implementing it in this way, you don't have to worry about alignments. You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128050/div-overlapping-sticky-footer) link helpful as well.

Edit 1: Since you want to preserve the alignment and avoid overlapping contenteditable boxes. Here is something I tried. All the boxes are editable.

[Updated JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrho9tze/3/)

**CSS**

```
.container {
    height: 1000px; 
    width:1000px; 
    background:white; 
    margin:50px auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 26.8%; left:41%">●</span><br>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 36.6%; left:41%">●</span><br>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 46.4%; left:41%">●</span><br>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 56.2%; left:41%">●</span><br>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 26.8%; left:24%">●</span><br>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 36.6%; left:24%">●</span><br>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 46.4%; left:24%">●</span><br>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 56.2%; left:24%">●</span><br>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 26.8%; left:75%">●</span><br>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 36.6%; left:75%">●</span><br>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 46.4%; left:75%">●</span><br>
<span contenteditable style="position:absolute; top: 56.2%; left:75%">●</span><br>
</div>
```

It gave me output like this:[image]

Edit 2:
I have put the text-align property. Check this out:

1. [Span tag without contenteditable](https://fiddle.jshell.net/yjbr6z0b/16/)
2. [Span tag with contenteditable](https://fiddle.jshell.net/pu1Lewrc/11/)

Try changing the text-align to right,left and center in both the links and execute.You can see the difference in link 1 alone. When you define the positions using contenteditable, then its inline property takes over your span class property. Thus, the only possible way you can align it is by removing contenteditable tag to bring the effect of span class property.

Comment: I don't want them one below the other, I need the alignment they have

Comment: I have edited the answer according to your requirement that I understood. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for helping, in the example you gave me the text isn't aligned to the center

Comment: Please check the Edit 2 in the answer above.

Comment: posted my solution below